# Not able to Run dataloader on win10 32 bit?

Tags: data-loader

I have installed ZULU openJDK 11. on my windows 10 32 bit machine.
Also installed dataloader.Not able to start the dataloader.

[image]

Comment: You can install older version of dataloader which doesn't require Zulu JDK. https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/38.0.0